# Can ultrasound be passed over the skin to be heard by the ear?

Tags: language, learning, ear

The company Skinlearning claims (in German), that one can learn "over the skin" with their [uSonic](http://www.skinlearning.info/usonic/technik/index.html) device.

Their site [says](http://www.skinlearning.info/usonic/wirkschema/index.html):

> So können Sie Ihren Lernstoff permanent wiederholen und damit in Ihrem Gedächtnis besser verankern und das ganz einfach neben Ihren sonstigen Beschäftigungen (Arbeiten, Fernsehen, Schlafen, …).

Translation:

> That way you can permanently repeat what you are learning and therefore memorize it better, all of that alongside your other activities (work, watching tv, sleep, ...).

They also mention on their website:

- [...] you can repeat vocabularies passively
- learn alongside you other activities unobtrusively and unnoticed

They provide these references:

- Medical College of Virginia, Summer 1991, names and papers not mentioned closer
- [Patrick Flanagan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Flanagan), the inventor (?)
- [Alfred A. Tomatis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Tomatis)

How I understand it [works](http://www.skinlearning.info/faqs/index.html): One inserts the desired audiofile into the device and applies the body pads to the skin (preferredly temple, lower arms, or hips). Now the pads generate ultrasound which somehow gets to the sacculus which is perfectly capable of perceiving the audiofile.

The manufacturer of the device [doesn't seem to repeat the claims](http://usonic.eu/downloads/uSonic_700N_Manual_e_2014.pdf), but makes their own [extraordinary clams](http://www.usonic.de/downloads/uSonic_info_e_2014.pdf).

The whole setup seems like a scam, but I'm no scientist.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). I'm trying to improve your question by finding the claims by uSonic. I see their claims that they can relax you with ultrasounds, but not that the user can perceive language. (The fact that my German is almost non-existent isn't helping.) Ultimately, audio does travel through your skin - your ear drum - but that's a pedantic answer.

Comment: [Claims, in English, by the manufacturers about relaxation](http://www.usonic.de/downloads/uSonic_info_e_2014.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: [User Manual, in English](http://usonic.eu/downloads/uSonic_700N_Manual_e_2014.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: @Oddthinking The claim is not made by Audivo or uSonic, but by "Skinlearning". I've added the claims from the site.